# Can not find Permissions assigned to created roles in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I logged in as SYSTEM in SQL dev and did this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = TRUE;

CREATE TABLE Attendance
(
    ID INT ,
    NAME NVARCHAR2(300),

    CONSTRAINT IdPk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE ROLE DataEntry;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON Attendance TO DataEntry;
```

How to find the permissions assigned to the DataEntry role? I've researched for a while, but the answers found didn't work. For example:

```
select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS;
select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS;
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS;
```

These statements return many many roles such as: dba,sys,.... But i still can't find my 'DataEntry' role. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks alot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using the undocumented _ORACLE_SCRIPT setting?  That's not something that users should be mucking around with unless Oracle Support has explicitly told you to.  It wouldn't shock me that marking the role as Oracle managed causes it to be excluded from some data dictionary views but I'm not going to test it locally to find out. https://mikedietrichde.com/2020/02/10/be-aware-when-you-use-_oracle_script-in-scripts/

Comment: View > DBA > Security > Roles, sqldev will show you everything you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created any objects connected as `SYSTEM`, you'd rather not do that. `SYS` and `SYSTEM` are special, don't mess up with them.

---

As of your question:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create role dataentry;

Role created.

SQL> grant select, insert, update on emp to dataentry;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select * From role_tab_privs;

ROLE       OWNER      TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM PRIVILEGE  GRA
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
DATAENTRY  SCOTT      EMP                   INSERT     NO
DATAENTRY  SCOTT      EMP                   SELECT     NO
DATAENTRY  SCOTT      EMP                   UPDATE     NO

SQL>
```

---

If you wanted to do such a query connected as a privileged user, then it is `dba_tab_privs`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select * From dba_tab_privs where owner = 'SCOTT';

GRANTEE      OWNER      TABLE_NAME GRANTOR    PRIVILEGE  GRA HIE
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---
MIKE         SCOTT      DEPT       SCOTT      DELETE     YES NO
DATAENTRY    SCOTT      EMP        SCOTT      INSERT     NO  NO
DATAENTRY    SCOTT      EMP        SCOTT      SELECT     NO  NO
DATAENTRY    SCOTT      EMP        SCOTT      UPDATE     NO  NO

SQL>
```

Comment: You can, but you won't get anything because it is ROLE_TAB_PRIVS (not "PRIVES"), and role name should be in uppercase: WHERE ROLE = 'DATAENTRY'

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged SQLDev...open the View menu, select DBA.

Add your connection. Expand, go to Security, Select Roles, open your Role.

Observe the Object Privs panel.

[image]

SQL Developer gets the object privs for a roles using this SQL

```
SELECT privilege   AS "Object Privilege"
     , owner       AS "Schema"
     , table_name  AS "Object"
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE grantee = :name -- DATAENTRY
 ORDER BY 2
        , 3
        , 1
```